# Create mutidimentional Associative array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create a multidimensional array in JavaScript

My code as follows but get console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'time' of undefined"

```
 var timeLogDetails = {};
  $('.time_input').each(function(i, obj) {
       timeLogDetails[i]['time'] = $( this ).val();
       timeLogDetails[i]['timeLog'] =  $( this ).attr('timelog');
  });
```

Comment: You need to create object instead of an array like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first create an array for `timeLogDetails`, and then push in data to it.

For example:

```
var timeLogDetails = [ ];

$('.time_input').each(function(i, obj) {

    timeLogDetails.push( {  
        'time': $(this).val(),
        'timeLog': $(this).attr('timelog')
    } ); 

});
```

Now, you may access the information using:

`timeLogDetails[0]['time']` or `timeLogDetails[0].time`

Comment: But now je is missing the i. He want set the time and the timelog for a specific index i think.

Comment: @hamala94 No, he doesn't. `i` will always be a numerical index starting at 0. Since the array (or object in his case) is empty to begin with, the code I posted above produces the same result as his would (if it worked).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each` like demonstrated by BenM, or [`$.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/). Both will produce array of objects:

```
var timeLogDetails = $('.time_input').map(function() {
    return {
        time: this.value,
        timeLog: $(this).attr('timelog')
    };
}).get();
```